# Sending an email using a business email with a pdf attachment fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, smtp

I'm sending an email using a business email with a PDF attachment which I generated at runtime using string data.

But it says

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at

Or

> Failure sending mail

My code follows:

```
protected void BtnSendEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Send_Email("moin.softwin@gmail.com","This is a mail with an attchment!","hello There, Have a good day. I have sent u an email with an attchment!");
}

protected string Bind_Invoice()
{
    string op = null;
    try
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(CommonClass.Get_DB_Path);
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("BIND_PURCHASE_INVOICE", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 10000;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USER", Session["username"].ToString());
        SqlParameter RuturnValue = new SqlParameter("@RETVAL", SqlDbType.VarChar, 18000);
        RuturnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(RuturnValue);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        op = cmd.Parameters["@RETVAL"].Value.ToString();
        cmd.Dispose();
        con.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex.Message != null)
        {
            op = ex.Message;
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    return op;
}

protected void Send_Email(string ToAddress, string MailSubject, string MailBody)
{
    try
    {
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.To.Add(ToAddress);// Email-ID of Receiver  
        message.Subject = MailSubject;// Subject of Email  
        message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("MYUSERNAME");// Email-ID of Sender  
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;

        string PDFdata = Bind_Invoice();
        MemoryStream file = new MemoryStream(PDFGenerate(PDFdata, Server.MapPath("img/bg.jpg")).ToArray());

        file.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        Attachment data = new Attachment(file, "RunTime_Attachment.pdf", "application/pdf");
        ContentDisposition disposition = data.ContentDisposition;
        disposition.CreationDate = System.DateTime.Now;
        disposition.ModificationDate = System.DateTime.Now;
        disposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Attachment;
        message.Attachments.Add(data);//Attach the file  

        message.Body = MailBody;
        SmtpClient SmtpMail = new SmtpClient();
        SmtpMail.Host = "MY HOST ADDRESS";//name or IP-Address of Host used for SMTP transactions  
        SmtpMail.Port = 465;//Port for sending the mail  
        SmtpMail.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("MYUSERNAME", "MYPASS");//username/password of network, if apply  
        SmtpMail.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        SmtpMail.EnableSsl = true;
        SmtpMail.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        SmtpMail.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 0;
        SmtpMail.ServicePoint.SetTcpKeepAlive(true, 2000, 2000);
        message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.Default;
        message.Priority = MailPriority.High;
        SmtpMail.Send(message); //Smtpclient to send the mail message  
        Response.Write("Email has been sent !");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 
        Response.Write("Failed !"); 
    } 
}

private MemoryStream PDFGenerate(string message, string ImagePath)
{
    MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 10, 25, 10);
    PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, output);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    Paragraph Text = new Paragraph(message);
    pdfDoc.Add(Text);
    byte[] file;
    file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(ImagePath);
    iTextSharp.text.Image jpg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(file);
    jpg.ScaleToFit(550F, 200F);
    pdfDoc.Add(jpg);
    pdfWriter.CloseStream = false;
    //pdfDoc.Close();
    output.Position = 0;
    return output;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ref: [SmtpClient Class documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-7.0) _We don't recommend that you use the SmtpClient class for new development because SmtpClient doesn't support many modern protocols. Use [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) or other libraries instead. For more information, see [SmtpClient shouldn't be used](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0005.md) on GitHub._

Comment: You might want to remove the adding of an Attachment and its creation in the shown code. Its presumably irrelevant in your problem and distracts as its more then half of the shown code. Port 465 does often more obscure things that SmtpClient has problems with if your smtp server surfaces Port 587 try that one. You might want to look into the Inner Exception of your  "Failure sending mail." Exception. It should contain more details about the problem.

Comment: Sidenote: Your code misses out to call Dispose on multiple objects. You are leaking resources here. Read on IDisposable and the using pattern in the docs.

Comment: If you want to test and debug SMTP during development, I'd recommend using https://mailsnag.com or a similar service and don't worry about actually delivering emails. It has an attachment and SMTP log explorer that might be useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting an authentication failure, that should be a separate issue from the attachment. Many providers (especially Google) now require two-factor authentication, and it's likely that if you're using one of these providers for your e-mail, you would have to get around that, first. For Gmail, you basically have to obtain a passcode for your application to log in with, instead of your normal password. This magically satisfies the two-factor requirement and allows you to send your e-mail. Here is the relevant discussion from Google's Support forum:

https://support.google.com/mail/thread/146949535/the-server-response-was-5-7-0-authentication-required?hl=en